# Double-clicking action button in dialogue can cause next review to be completed without voting

Tags: bug, review, user-interface

While reviewing low quality posts, I accidentally clicked the Delete button twice in quick succession on the dialogue for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4719389). It caused [the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4719366) to flash by quickly, and it counted as a review, but no vote was cast (as I’m a moderator on Stack Overflow, it would have been deleted immediately, too):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you still reproduce this? I'm not able to.

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, sort of. It acted like the Skip button this time; no review was counted.

Comment: @Shog9: [Reproduced again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5668662), after accidentally double-clicking on the action in [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5668735).